# How to find the stored procedures acting on a table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table in a database. The fields of the table are being updating by some stored procedure from some other table. Is there any possibility that I can find the stored procedures which are acting on a particular table???

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which stored procedures are likely to touch your table, you could search that in sys.procedures something on the lines of:

```
select * from sys.procedures 
where object_definition(object_id) like '%tablename%'

-- or probe information_schema
select * from information_schema.routines
where routine_definition like '%tablename%'
```

**Object_Definition**

> Returns the Transact-SQL source text of the definition of a specified object.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090(v=sql.105).aspx

When we look into sys.procedures, there'll be a field called object_id. Each object in SQL Server has an ID. `object_definition` will retrieve definition of that object - in our case, text of the procedure will be retrieved.

Comment: What information does `object_definition(object_id)` returns ? Could you elaborate please ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` view.

But this won't work if the SP build dynamic SQL to access the table (not schema bound). You might need to use trace or SQL Profiler to help out.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you use this query. You got  a list store procedure in actual database

```
 SELECT ROUTINE_NAME   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE= 'PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: Question purpose is to know about stored procedure from table name. Not the List of stored procedures existing in db.